# Play one video at a time with react-native-video

Tags: react-native, react-native-video

In my application I have a list with several videos, and I am currently facing a great difficulty, when I click to play a specific video the other one that was already playing does not pause, I already looked in the docs of the react-native-video lib but without success. Has anyone experienced this problem? And do you have any ideas on how to solve it?